# What does $V^*$ represent in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

If $V$ is a vector space, then what does the notation $V^*$ normally stand for?

Thank-you

Comment: The space of linear functionals $V\to K$, where $K$ is the scalar field of $V$.

Comment: Also known as the "Dual Space" of V,  but the exact same concept as Daniel, above.

Comment: $V$ is a $k$-vector space over the field $k$, then $V^{*}:=\text{Hom}_k(V,k)$